# How to store access token? (Oauth 2, Auth code flow)

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

From what i understand the purpose of the Authorization Code flow is to exchange the auth code for access token. This exchange happens between the server which serves the page and authorization server so that the actual access token is not exposed to the client user.

How should the page server store the access token once it is obtained? I was learning from a Pluralsight example in which there is this part of code:

```
    public static HttpClient GetClient()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var accessToken = RequestAccessTokenAuthorizationCode();
        client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(IdentityConstants.API);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        return client;
    }

    private static string RequestAccessTokenAuthorizationCode()
    {
        // did we store the token before?
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("ClientMVCCookie.AuthCode");
        if (cookie != null && cookie["access_token"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie["access_token"]))
        {
            return cookie["access_token"];
        }

        // no token found - request one

        // we'll pass through the URI we want to return to as state
        var state = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString;

        var authorizeRequest = new IdentityModel.Client.AuthorizeRequest(
            IdentityConstants.AuthEndoint);

        var url = authorizeRequest.CreateAuthorizeUrl(IdentityConstants.MVCClientSecret, "code", "management secret",
            IdentityConstants.MVCAuthCodeCallback, state);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);

        return null;
    }
}
```

This will cause each request to check if there is an access token stored in the cookie. If not then the flow will be initiated. The callback looks like this:

```
public class CallbackController : Controller
{
    // GET: STSCallback
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        // get the authorization code from the query string
        var authCode = Request.QueryString["code"];

        // with the auth code, we can request an access token.
        var client = new TokenClient(
            IdentityConstants.TokenEndoint,
            "mvc_client_auth_code",
             IdentityConstants.MVCClientSecretAuthCode);

        var tokenResponse = await client.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(
            authCode,
            IdentityConstants.MVCAuthCodeCallback);

        // we save the token in a cookie for use later on
        var cookie = Response.Cookies["ClientMVCCookie.AuthCode"];
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
        cookie["access_token"] = tokenResponse.AccessToken;

        // get the state (uri to return to)
        var state = Request.QueryString["state"];

        // redirect to the URI saved in state
        return Redirect(state);
    }
}
```

Doesn't storing the access token in the cookie defeath the whole purpose of the authorization code flow? The cookie will be transmitted to the client browser thus exposing it to the client? Am i missing something? It this is not the correct way to store the token, how should it be stored?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The client, in OAuth terminology, is the component that makes requests to the resource server, in your case, the client is the server of a web application (NOT the browser).

Therefore, the access token should be stored on the web application server only. It should not be exposed to the browser, and it doesn't need to, because the browser never makes any direct requests to the resource server. It talks to the web application server instead, which in turn makes requests to the resource server using the access token.

How the browser authenticates itself with the web application server has nothing to do with OAuth 2.0. For example, it might be a regular session cookie, and the web application server might associate each session or each user with an access token.

The token request, which exchanges the authentication code for an access token, is done by the web application server, and the web application server should authenticate itself with the authorization server (e.g., using a shared `client_secret`).

Authorization code flow ensures that the client can be authenticated, which protects against malicious clients posing as legitimate clients. Not all web application clients have a server component, and in some cases, requests to the resource server are made directly by JavaScript code in the browser. In such situations, the browser is the client, and the access token must be stored by the browser (in a JavaScript variable, local storage or a cookie). In this case, the client cannot be authenticated (but a reasonable amount of security may be achieved by using TLS and the server redirecting only to registered endpoint URLs).

Recommended reading regarding OAuth 2.0 security: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.3.3 (RFC 6819)

Comment: I totally understand that part. I was asking if the example i have included in the question is correct. The example uses a cookie on the ASP.NET MVC server. I thought that this cookie which includes the token would get passed to the browser (would it?) which would expose the token.

Comment: It is difficult to analyze this code without an explanation what it _is_. Part of the authorization server? The client?

Comment: It is an mvc server side application. The callback controller exchanges the auth code with the authorization server for the access token. It then includes the token in the cookie. This is an example i have found. I know that the token can't be exposed to the browser. This is why it buffles me why it is saved in a cookie. Doesn't it mean that it will travel along with subsequent requests to the browser?

Comment: Should we encrypt this access token at rest?

Comment: @JuanGaitán - that is the question I'm looking for an answer to also

Comment: If you store the access token (or refresh token) in persistent storage (a database, or on disk), then you may want to encrypt it (and the entire database and disk) at rest. There really isn't a good reason to not encrypt it. If the access token is short-lived (e.g., a JWT which is renewed using a refresh token), then it is likely only kept in memory or a key/value store until it expires, and because it will expire, encryption may be less important.

Comment: @FlorianWinter if the access token is short-lived, e.g. expires after one hour, when leaving it in memory do you also have to write code to associate an access token with each session or each user? So that when the user signs out that access token becomes invalid, and also only that user has access to that token. I'm also wondering how you would make this association in ASP.NET MVC particularly using ASP.NET Core Identity.

Comment: Yes, if the access token delegates a user's permission on a resource server to the client (the web application), then the client has to associate the access token with a user session. This is outside the scope of OAuth. How to do this, and how access tokens are invalidated depends on the web framework you are using and the API you are connecting to. My answer was only about OAuth in general.

Comment: This really baffles me, in cases where frontend client has a backend component (back-channel) you are saying that only the server side should store the token? Isn't it defeats the whole purpose of JWT tokens? if JWT/Access tokens etc. are stored in backend - then now you need to track it, maintain it, what if backend wants to scale up? now you need a single point of storage (Db) WOW this defeats the "Self contained" idea of JWT tokens. Don't you think that having tokens stored in frontend client memory + using TLS encryption, and implementing PKCE  should supply an equivalent security?

Comment: Even more - I think that storing tokens in the client-backend makes it even easier for hackers. Now all the hacker must do is to impersonate a client frontend request (with no tokens) just steal cookies which is ALOT easier than stealing a token. and boom you are now the resource owner.

Comment: @Mercury If you are requesting and storing access tokens in the front-end, you are creating a public client. This is a different OAuth flow and common practice, and there is nothing wrong with it. If you use CORS+PKCE rather than implicit grant, this is also as secure as a native client. You can also use this if you have a back-end, but I think it depends mostly on where your API requests are made (front-end or back-end).

Comment: @Mercury As for cookies vs. sessions: 1) Cookies are only an example of how to do front-end to back-end auth. If the back-end is the OAuth client, this is outside the scope of OAuth, which is the main point of my answer. 2) I will not argue for either cookies or tokens, but rather point you to this http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/ and this counter-position: https://www.ducktypelabs.com/review-stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/. Most arguments we will likely come up with are already covered there. My opinion is that both are fine and have their pros and cons.

Answer (score 6):

The cookie is never exposed to the browser. It is part of the response returned from the authorization server to the client, which itself is a server, not a browser. The `CallbackController`, which implements the redirection endpoint, extracts the cookie from the response.

The cookie is never passed on to the browser. How the browser authenticates itself with the client's application server is not shown in your sample code, and it is not part of OAuth.

The authorization server could store the token in the request body (e.g., in JSON format) rather than in a cookie. However, this makes no difference, because the client can see and process the entire response anyway.

For details, see my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44655679/2279059

Side note: The `CallbackController` uses `state` to store a final URL to redirect the browser to. This is non-standard but works. However, `state` is actually meant to protect the redirection endpoints against CSRF attacks. The `CallbackController` does not validate `state` but blindly redirects to whatever URL was given. Probably this detail was left out, because the code was meant as an example. However, it shows that this code is probably not entirely production-ready.

Comment: Thank You ;) that is exactly what i was missing. The client does not necessarily pass the cookie to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to request a rest resource from the browser, the flow you need is `Implicit Grant`. Check this `Auth0` post to decide between the flows https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use. If you want to use the access token from server you should store the `Authorization code` and generate an `access token` every time you need it, `access token` is not intended to live more than 5 minutes, you don't need to store it

Comment: The `authorization code` has a shorter lifetime than most of `access tokens` 
https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/authorization/the-authorization-response/
> "The authorization code must expire shortly after it is issued. The OAuth 2.0 spec recommends a maximum lifetime of 10 minutes, but in practice, most services set the expiration much shorter, around 30-60 seconds. [...].
Because authorization codes are meant to be short-lived and single-use [...]"
So why not store the access_token and the refresh_token ?

Comment: Single page web applications can also use authorization code flow with PKCE. It only requires the authorization server to have CORS enabled, which is usually already a requirement if the authorization server is also the resource server. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHzERullHe8, and https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-00

Comment: As said by @jona303, authorization code is single use only.  If you want to keep the *user's* access token on the server, you'll want to keep and use the refresh token.  For a server identity/token, simply use `client_credentials` flow to retrieve a fresh access token shortly before it expires.